# login with www::mechanize on a unnamed form with unnamed submit

Tags: perl, authentication, www-mechanize

i want to login ( stable ) with perl to a web site like http://site/signin/index.php.
this page have form and submit without name.
how can i login ?
this is a example code to login:

```
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech -> cookie_jar(HTTP::Cookies->new());
$mech -> get($login_url);
$mech -> form_name('theform');
$mech -> field ('username' => $username);
$mech -> field ('password' => $password);
$mech -> click ('log in');
print $mech-> content();
```

this is my form

```
<form method="post" action="">
<table id="regform" cellspacing="5">
<tr>
<td class="regparam">email:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="email" value="" tabindex="1" maxlength="100" style="font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 10pt;  font-weight: bold; border: 1px solid #9AD7F8; background-color: #ffffff" class="reginp" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="regparam">password:</td>
<td><input type="password" name="password" value="" tabindex="2" maxlength="100" style="font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 10pt;  font-weight: bold; border: 1px solid #9AD7F8; background-color: #ffffff"  class="keyboardInput" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td valign="middle">
<button type="submit" style="font-weight:bold; tabindex="4" class="subm-posts">login</button>
<label style="margin:0px; padding:0px; margin-left:10px; margin-top:7px; float:left; clear:none;">
<input type="checkbox" name="rememberme" value="1"  tabindex="3" />
<span style="padding:2px; padding-left:5px;">remember me</span>
</label>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of referring to the form by name, you can refer to it by [number](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/WWW-Mechanize-1.71/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm#FORM_METHODS), i.e. where it appears in the form:

```
$mech->form_number( 1 );
```

Form numbers start from one.

Similarly, as there is only [one button](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/WWW-Mechanize-1.71/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm#%24mech-%3Eclick%28_%24button_%5B,_%24x,_%24y%5D_%29) in the form, you can just use

```
$mech->click( );
```

and that will submit the form as it will click the button.

Answer (score 0):

```
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->cookie_jar( HTTP::Cookies->new() );
$mech->get($login_url);

$mech->submit_form(
    form_name => 'theform',
    fields    => {
        username => $username,
        password => $password,
    },
);

print $mech->content();
```

Comment: @sali444 please post correct code to get correct answers, editing later on will not change previously posted answers.